# create fonts subset using opentype.js getting "OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to parse table" error

Tags: node.js, fonts, opentype

I trying to create a font subset with opentype.js in node

my code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const opentype = require('opentype.js');

let font = opentype.loadSync('./SourceHanSansCN-Heavy.otf');
let subfontGlyph = font.stringToGlyphs('一大段文字中文字体子集');

let subfont = new opentype.Font({
  familyName: 'SourceHanSansCN-Heavy',
  styleName: 'Heavy',
  unitsPerEm: font.unitsPerEm,
  ascender: font.ascender,
  descender: font.descender,
  glyphs: subfontGlyph
});


fs.writeFileSync('./sub.otf', Buffer.from(subfont.toArrayBuffer()));
```

and I try to use `sub.otf` in browser;

but chrome is complaining the font file

```
OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to parse table
```

(StackOverflow editor does not allow me to input Chinese characters in code block);

and I find this problem only happens when create glyph with **non-latin** characters.

Comment: Check if the font file referenced exists and is valid. Otherwise check char by car by `Font.charToGlyph`

Comment: @bato3 font file is exist, but I don't know how to "check char by car"

Comment: I assume you asked this over on the OpenType.js [issue tracker](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/issues)? Can you please put the link for the issue in your post? (and if you haven't: remember that SO is your last resort, when even asking the people who run the open source project you're relying on can't help, or the project explicitly says to use stackoverflow for questions instead of filing an issue. But that is not the case here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnally find that the string pass to `font.stringToGlyph` has duplicated characters. I have to remove the dupcated ones by myself

```
function rmDupChar(text) {
  return [...new Set(text.split(''))].join('');
}

let subfontGlyph = font.stringToGlyphs(rmDupChar('一大段文字中文字体子集'));
```

Comment: Have you meet issue `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when calling `toArrayBuffer` funtion?